# Content-Security-Policy + Angular 8

Tags: angular

Estou aplicando a seguinte política de segurança em um projeto:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="script-src 'self'; style-src 'self'; img-src 'self';" />
```

No console, recebo os seguintes erros:

[image: Erros Console]

Já tentei utilizar:

`npm build --prod`
`npm run build --prod`
`npm build --aot --prod`

Mais nenhuma das opções funcionou. Alguém já passou por algo parecido?

Comment: Já tentou `ng build --prod`?

Answer (score 0):

Pra que o Angular possa aplicar estilos dinâmicos nos elementos na keyword `style-src` você deve complementar com `'unsafe-inline'`

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="script-src 'self'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; img-src 'self';" />
```